# Javascript to FHIRPath

Tags: hl7-fhir

We have existing Form(s) with embedded javascript validation expressions. We are trying to convert these expressions to FHIRPath, so that we can embed them as FHIRPath expressions in our Questionnaire responses.
At present, we are attempting to parse these javascript blocks into FHIRPath, but it is challenging and does not seem to be the best way to proceed.
Are there any suggestions on how to tackle this - is there a Javascript to FHIRPath converter that could be used or any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an existing javascript to fhirpath converter out there - haven't heard of one. If I were to go about doing this, I'd convert Javascript AST to FHIRpath, that would be the most foulproof way to do it. You can find quite a few libraries that can parse Javascript into AST out there.

Comment: Thanks Vadi - we will evaluate this approach

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is very difficult. FHIRPath and Javascript are just so radically different in how they go about things - an object based procedural language, and a path based query language with no variables. XPath --> FHIRPath, I could imagine trying to have a go at that. And FHIRPath --> Javascript, yes, I could imagine that too. but not the other way

Comment: Thanks Grahame. In that case, would an approach of embedding javascript snippets as extensions within the Questionnaire response be advisable? We want to be FHIR compliant - would something like this result in non-compliance or rejection by FHIR consumers?

Comment: Well, you can put extensions in, sure. but they'll be ignored by any system that doesn't know the extension. Mind you, any validation expression, whatever language it is in, will be an extension